# WebDeploy command line tool to skip web.config file

Tags: iis, deployment, web, command, msdeploy

I want webdeploy commandline command to skip - Delete / Update of web.config file and Website host header updates. How do i do that.

Currently command line ignores any skip command and updates binding to reflect non-production bindings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for a skip rule:

```
msdeploy -verb:sync -source:<your_source> -dest:<your_source> ^
         -skip:File=web\.config
```

Comment: Thanks Richard for answer and a great blog-post about MSDeploy.